# Getting err_too_many_redirects in HandleUnauthorizedRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am working in MVC. I got error

> err_too_many_redirects

in

> HandleUnauthorizedRequest

.

```
public class AuthCheckService : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            //Ajax request doesn't return to login page, it just returns 403 error.
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 501;
            throw new ModelStateException("Your Session has expired- Please login again!");
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            //filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Login", controller = "Account" }));
        }

    }
}
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong?

Comment: Your error sounds like you have the Authorize attribute on your error handler page.  Your work flow is going something like this:  Request Page A -> Unauthorized, redirect to Unauthorized error page, request unauthorized error page, not authorized, redirect to Unauthorized error page.....rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one silly mistake i had done during testing in web config file:

```
 <sessionState timeout="2" cookieName="OnshoreMaintSSID" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Account/Login" timeout="1" name=".Onshore" requireSSL="false" />
</authentication>
<pages>
```

as you can see above sessionstate timeout is greater than forms authentication timeout. This is causing the issue.

**Solution:**

```
 <sessionState timeout="1" cookieName="OnshoreMaintSSID" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Account/Login" timeout="2" name=".Onshore" requireSSL="false" />
</authentication>
<pages>
```

Hope this will help some one else.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. If you have integrated your application with Azure SSO page, you need to check the sessionState attribute in web.config. cookieSameSite should be configured with "Lax" or "None" value.

Change

```
    <sessionState cookieSameSite="Strict" timeout="20"/>
```

to

```
    <sessionState cookieSameSite="Lax" timeout="20"/>
```

to get rid of this error.